# jQuery/Google Maps: Location picker with radius control?

Tags: dictionary, geolocation, location

I'm looking for a simple user friendly way of selecting a location by getting the lat/long position along with a radius of influence.

I've seen a similar thing done while selecting ad display areas in google ads. I wonder is there a jQuery/Google solution to this? or have you seen something similar i can implement?

I just need a center (lat/long) and radius.

P.S. This is for the UK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I settled on something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>

        <!-- TITLE -->
        <title>Website Title</title>

        <!-- META -->
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

        <!-- JAVASCRIPT -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src='http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false'></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function(){

                var Circle = null;
                var Radius = $("#radius").val();

                var StartPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(54.19335, -3.92695);

                function DrawCircle(Map, Center, Radius) {

                    if (Circle != null) {
                        Circle.setMap(null);
                    }

                    if(Radius > 0) {
                        Radius *= 1609.344;
                        Circle = new google.maps.Circle({
                            center: Center,
                            radius: Radius,
                            strokeColor: "#0000FF",
                            strokeOpacity: 0.35,
                            strokeWeight: 2,
                            fillColor: "#0000FF",
                            fillOpacity: 0.20,
                            map: Map
                        });
                    }
                }

                function SetPosition(Location, Viewport) {
                    Marker.setPosition(Location);
                    if(Viewport){
                        Map.fitBounds(Viewport);
                        Map.setZoom(map.getZoom() + 2);
                    }
                    else {
                        Map.panTo(Location);
                    }
                    Radius = $("#radius").val();
                    DrawCircle(Map, Location, Radius);
                    $("#latitude").val(Location.lat().toFixed(5));
                    $("#longitude").val(Location.lng().toFixed(5));
                }

                var MapOptions = {
                    zoom: 5,
                    center: StartPosition,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                    mapTypeControl: false,
                    disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
                    streetViewControl: false
                };

                var MapView = $("#map");
                var Map = new google.maps.Map(MapView.get(0), MapOptions);

                var Marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: StartPosition, 
                    map: Map, 
                    title: "Drag Me",
                    draggable: true
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener(Marker, "dragend", function(event) {
                    SetPosition(Marker.position);
                });

                $("#radius").keyup(function(){
                    google.maps.event.trigger(Marker, "dragend");
                });

                DrawCircle(Map, StartPosition, Radius);
                SetPosition(Marker.position);

            });

        </script>

    </head>

    <body>

        <form>

            Latitude: <input type="text" id="latitude" /> Longitude: <input type="text" id="longitude" />
            Radius: <input type="text" id="radius" value="320" />

            <div id="map" style="width:600px; height:400px; background-color:#000000;">


            </div>

        </form>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: You'll notice the word 'something' in the answer because this wasn't the finished code and wasn't tested. Also the link you provided does actually work so why would you say it doesn't? If it doesn't work for you, then MAKE it work or are you a 'Gimmeh teh codez' person? Down-voting the only answer that i wasn't forced to give (especially code) makes you look like a complete tool. Why don't you provide an answer yourself?

Comment: I downvoted your answer, because I wanted to give you the chance to make it better, before I report it. As it is a very poor answer. As you said, its untested (unconfirmed), it lacks documentation and comments. Its just a paste of something little bit relevant to the question. If anyone else but you would have asked this question, your answer wouldn't have gotten the accept. As for location picker the inputs wont update so the code doesn't work. Period.
If you wish to submit untested and nonworking code, please put a disclaimer.

Comment: Oh, you have to drag pointer. I see, in that case I must apologize. I will edit your answer, so I could change my vote (feel free to override it).

Comment: I would much appreciate it, if you could edit your answer. Maybe add a quick note, that you must drag it.. as most of these pickers work on the center position of the current map. I would really love to change my vote, as this code is very valuable.

Comment: Hey, after that little tiff, I think you deserve a nice thanks, extremely useful code and works fine.